# Can the zero set of an irreducible polynomial contain a non-empty Zariski open subset?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$ be an irreducible polynomial.
>
> Is it possible that $Z(f)$, the zero set of $f$, contains a non-empty Zariski open subset of $\mathbb A^n(k)$ ? (By $\mathbb A^n(k)$ I  don't mean $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x_1,...,x_n])$, rather only the closed points.)

I know that it is impossible for $n=1$. Also when $k=\mathbb C$, I know it is impossible for all $n$, in fact then the zero set can't even contain any non-empty Euclidean open set. But I'm not sure what happens in other cases.

Comment: No for dimension reasons.

Comment: If you mean the scheme version, no, since non-empty open subsets of the integral scheme $\Bbb A^n_k$ are of dimension $n$ but $V(f)$ is of dimension $n-1$ for any nonzero $f\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. If you mean $Z(f)=\{x\in k^n\mid f(x)=0\}$, then yes, take $k=\Bbb F_2$, $n=1$, and $f=x^2-x$.

Comment: @KReiser Your last example fails to have $k$ algebraically closed.

Comment: @Servaes Ugh, this is what I get for going too fast. Thanks for pointing it out - with $k$ algebraically closed this is always true even if you take the non-scheme version.

Comment: @KReiser: I'm not sure what you mean by scheme version ... anyway I'm taking only the closed points of the spectrum ... set inclusion doesn't depend on scheme structure I believe ...

Comment: As originally written, your post read $\Bbb A^n_k$, which is usually meant to be $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, instead of $k^n=\Bbb A^n_k(k)$. You later edited your post to make it read the latter, which is the "non-scheme" version. As $A^n_k(k)$ is not always dense in $\Bbb A^n_k$ (see the example from the first comment), it's worth pointing out that the formulation matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $U \subseteq \mathbf{A}^{n}$ is nonempty and open, then $\text{dim }U=\text{dim }\overline{U}=\text{dim }\mathbf{A}^{n}=n$.
 
Now if $U \subseteq Z(f)$, then $\text{dim }U \leq \text{dim }Z(f) = n-1$, which is impossible.

Here are the relevant facts used from Ch. 1, Sec. 1 in Hartshorne (valid over any algebraically closed field): 
$\bullet$ The dimension of a quasi-affine variety is the same as its closure (Proposition 1.10) 
$\bullet$ $\mathbf{A}^{n}$ is irreducible (its ideal is prime: $I(\mathbf{A^{n}})=0$), and a nonempty open subset of an irreducible space is dense (Exercise 1.6) 
$\bullet$ The dimension of $\mathbf{A}^{n}$ is $n$ (Proposition 1.9) 
$\bullet$ If $Y \subseteq X$ are topological spaces, then $\text{dim }Y \leq \text{dim }X$ (Exercise 1.10a)

$\bullet$ $Z(f)$ has dimension $n-1$ (Proposition 1.13)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $Z(f)$ contains the open subset $U$, the complementary $C$ of $U$ is closed and is $V(I)$ this implies that $Z(f)\cup V(I)=V(fI)$ is the whole space the theorem of zero implies that $If=0$ contradiction

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted ... unless I'm missing anything, this is a perfectly valid answer ...